# Creating a PHP extension extending another PHP extension?

Tags: php, memcached

I searched over the Internet several documentation about how to create PHP extensions, but unfortunately, there is nothing about linking to another extensions (and making a requirement for having that extension loaded prior to the new it is being created).

I guess I could simply #include necessary header files into my source code, but not sure about linking.

As an example, and to play with extension creation, the first I want to create is a solution I implemented to allow namespaces in memcached [github](https://github.com/StormBytePP/NSSMemcache) but wanted to know how to use other extensions' code from my custom extension one for other usages as well.

Comment: If it can be easily implemented on client side (php) - why to complicate memcached extension with this?

Comment: I did it in client side, but though the posibility of having it as an extension. It will not complicate memcached extension, only to add that as a extension too so original memcached is not modifyed.

Comment: Yes, but for what reason? memcached provides general functionality, and your application implements some specifics.

Comment: Well, I should have more clear, that is just an example, but the question still apply. I update the question.

Comment: @zerkms Also, in that specific issue, is to try to optimize it by having my specifics as an extension (if it could be done), and code them in C to be run nativelly by PHP instead of interpreting the script each time. (That class is heavily used)

Comment: "in that specific issue, is to try to optimize it by having my specifics as an extension" --- so you want to optimize one concatenation operation (obviously you just prepend variable name with namespace name)??

Comment: read better the code. it does not "just prepend" variable name to namespace nor by far anything like that. So "obviously" don't be that harsh with me, specially if you are not right. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to reply to the thread with StormByte, but it sounds like you need to do some load balancing or caching, not extending PHP.

If you really want to do this at the code level, you could use `exec()` to call a Python script, [which gets compiled into byte code automatically](http://effbot.org/zone/python-compile.htm).